# how read data from sharepoint list in asp.net site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint

I have some data in sharepoint lists,I want to read particular data from the list and show them in my asp.net website,what should i do ?

I don't want use sharepoint linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft SharePoint 2010 introduces new REST-based web services by using Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) Data Services http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134614(v=office.14).aspx 
Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18624371/820436

Comment: Thank you, but I cant use (Microsoft.sharepoint) dll, I prefer to read data in my web, and find my info , show it like a text, do you have any solution ?

Comment: The web service allow you connect it to other applications on any platform / technology, and other computers on the network. 
Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll is not need. Just add web service reference to your asp.net application

Answer (score 1):

You can read data from SharePoint in your ASP.NET Using SharePoint CSOM.

`Client-Side Object Model (CSOM)` is mainly used to build client applications and enable us to access SharePoint Sites that are hosted outside without using web services.

**What do you need in order to use CSOM?**

You just needed to add the below assemblies as a reference to your solution to be able to work with the Client Object Model.

- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

These assemblies can be found in the 14 Hive folder: `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\ISAPI.` So you should copy it first from your SharePoint Server to your solution folder then add it as a reference in your solution.

For Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code check

- [Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx)
- [SharePoint Client Object Modal (CSOM)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-client-object-modal-csom/)
- [SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model: Introduction](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/399156/sharepoint-client-object-model-introduction)

Also, you can Accessing SharePoint 2010 Lists by Using `REST-based web services` for more details/ examples check this MSDN article [Accessing SharePoint 2010 Lists by Using WCF Data Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134614(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API to retrieve SharePoint list items. You can use REST API in C# and also in java-script.

The following is the java-script code which retrieves list (Employee) items from the sharepoint devsite using REST API.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"       src="https://name.sharepoint.com/sites/devsite/SiteAssets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#getEmployee').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
    url:      "https://name.sharepoint.com/sites/devsite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')       /items",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        *** You can Parse your data under this function*** 
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Response fails");
    }
   })
   })

   })
    </script>
 <input type="button" value="GET" name="GET" id="getEmployee"/>
```